# How to compile Qt MySQL driver in Windows

Tags: mysql, qt

I run:

```bash
C:\Qt\6.6.1\Src>configure.bat -sql-mysql
```

but got:

```
+ cd qtbase
+ C:\Qt\6.6.1\Src\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level -sql-mysql
-- Windows 10 SDK version:
'C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe' '-DQT_INTERNAL_CALLED_FROM_CONFIGURE:BOOL=TRUE' '-DINPUT_sql_mysql=yes' '-G' 'Ninja' 'C:/Qt/6.6.1/Src'
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.33130.0
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.33130.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: 'C:/Qt/6.6.1/Src/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-ul5gvm'

    Run Build Command(s): C:/PROGRA~1/Ninja/ninja.exe -v cmTC_4c278
    [1/2] C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1438~1.331\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe  /nologo /TP   /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /EHsc  /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -MDd /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_4c278.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_4c278.dir\ /FS -c C:\Qt\6.6.1\Src\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-ul5gvm\testCXXCompiler.cxx
    [2/2] C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_4c278.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1438~1.331\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_4c278.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj  /out:cmTC_4c278.exe /implib:cmTC_4c278.lib /pdb:cmTC_4c278.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    FAILED: cmTC_4c278.exe
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_4c278.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1438~1.331\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_4c278.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj  /out:cmTC_4c278.exe /implib:cmTC_4c278.lib /pdb:cmTC_4c278.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_4c278.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_4c278.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    no such file or directory
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

In a Qt project that will use MySQL driver, I had to use MinGW compiler. I set CXX system variable to `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw1120_64\bin\gcc.exe` but it still tries to compile using MSVC.

How do I fix this?